# Optional argument identifiers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning iOS and Swift development and have a question about function argument identifiers. This is the signature for `UIButton.setText` as it appears when Xcode suggests the type-ahead:

```
// Xcode type-ahead signature:
sender.setTitle(title: String?, forState: UIControlState)
```

And when I copy and paste that it inserts some more information, like this:

```
// Actual signature from documentation:
sender.setTitle(<#title: String?#>, forState: <#UIControlState#>)
```

My usage is like this:

```
sender.setTitle("Hello World", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

As you can see, **the `forState` argument identifier is required, but the `title` identifer is not. How can I determine this from Xcode's type-ahead method signature suggestion?** Does the `?` in `title: String?` denote the identifier as optional? If not, what does that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> … the `forState` argument identifier is required, but the `title` identifer is not.  How can I determine this from Xcode's type-ahead method signature suggestion?

Here's what the template looks like on-screen:

[image: setTitle template]

Notice that the first placeholder contains `title: String?`, while the second placeholder only contains `UIControlState` (and does **not** contain `forTitle:`).  This is how you know that the first argument doesn't require a keyword, but the second argument does.  This also makes your <kbd>tab</kbd> key automatically select the right amount of text to replace.  (You can also use Navigate > Jump to Next Placeholder <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, if <kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't work.)

Your pasted copy looks like this:

```
sender.setTitle(<#title: String?#>, forState: <#UIControlState#>)
```

The `<# ... #>` is how Xcode represents a placeholder.  Notice again that the first argument, including keyword, is inside `<# ... #>`, but the second placeholder excludes the keyword `forState:` and only includes the type `UIControlState`.

You can use this syntax to create placeholders in your own custom snippets.  You just type `<#` and `#>` into the snippet.  As soon as you finish typing `#>`, Xcode will convert the annotated text to a placeholder.  Demonstration:

[image: snippet demonstration]

The `?` after `String` indicates an optional string.  It's syntactic sugar for `Optional<String>`.  You can learn more about `Optional` by reading the section titled “Optionals” in [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Comment: what's this?! a non-fixed-width font?!

Comment: yeah looks nice :) just wired to see a non-fixed-width font being used for programming

Comment: Note: there's another use for '#' in Swift for external parameter name same as internal. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382118/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-mark-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to tell:

1. Swift's rule for parameter labels *in methods* is that the first parameter label is omitted when calling and te rest are required. This mimics convention from Objective-C where the method name and first parameter label run together — `setTitle` already references a title, so it'd sound funny if it read `setTitle(title:...`. Like in ObjC, Swift method calls should read like sentences.
2. When you select the method in autocomplete, Xcode leaves placeholders for the text you're supposed to replace with your own code. Those show up as blue ovals in Xcode, but they're actually just text delimited by `<# #>` as you can see from when you pasted it into your question.

   The parts of the autocomplete text that are placeholders are things you need to fill in to complete the method call; the parts not in placeholders are the required syntax for calling that method. In your example, `title:` is inside the placeholder for the first parameter, so you don't write it when calling the method, and `forState:` is not in a placeholder, so you do write it when calling the method.