# currying in Swift, new declaration syntax in future?

Tags: swift

Just installed Swift today in Linux to check it out.

Trying a small example of currying results in a warning that the syntax for currying will change in the future, however I could not find anything about what this new syntax looks like.

The currying example I tried:

```
func do_stuff(x: Int) (y: Int) (z: Int) -> Int {
    return (x - y) * z
}
let curry_fun = do_stuff(42)
let x = curry_fun(y: 7)(z: 3)
```

compiling this example results in following warning:

```
warning: curried function declaration syntax will be removed in a future version of Swift; use a single parameter list
func do_stuff(x: Int) (y: Int) (z: Int) -> Int {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    ,        ,
```

**So what does currying then look like in future swift?**

*I did try something like* `func do_stuff(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) -> Int...` *, however I couldn't find a way to do currying with that function..*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

only the declaration syntax will be removed e.g. `func(a: Int)(b:Int) -> Int`

```
func curry(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
func newCurry(a: Int) -> (b: Int) -> Int {
    return { b in
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand they plan to remove it completely.

Here is a quote from the [swift-evolution github repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md):

> Curried function declaration syntax func `foo(x: Int)(y: Int)` is of limited usefulness and creates a lot of language and implementation complexity. We should remove it.

Comment: So future swift will not support currying?.. that sucks :(

Comment: Ah, I see they are considering an alternative syntax as well.. I hope that's what they end up doing.. Anyways, thanks for explanation :)

Comment: @Mitzh, yes, it's still a "proposal" (although, accepted), so if you think you have good use-cases or ideas how to improve the situation then there is  [another page in that repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/process.md) that explains how can you influence the decision.

Comment: I found a case that seems to only work when using the curried form of a swift function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423428/swift-subtle-difference-between-curried-and-higher-order-function I looked at that page but it looks like this proposal is already out of review, is there a way to bring this question up still?

Answer (score 0):

Curried function declaration syntax has been removed in `Swift3`, we should use the parameter list instead.