# Swift subtle difference between curried and higher order function

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions, currying

NOTE: This question was asked while Swift 2.1 was the latest.

Given:

```
class IntWrapper {
    var i: Int = 1
}
func add(inout m: Int, i: Int) {
    m += i
}
```

And a higher order function

```
func apply() -> (inout i: Int) -> () -> () {
    return { (inout i: Int) -> () -> () in
        return {
            add(&i, i: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Application as so results in the member variable value never changing:

```
var intW = IntWrapper()
print(intW.i)                             // Prints '1'
apply()(i: &intW.i)()
print(intW.i)                             // Prints '1'
```

However, when changing the function to curried form

```
func apply()(inout i: Int)() -> () {
    add(&i, i: 1)
}
```

Application results in the member variable value changing:

```
var intW = IntWrapper()
print(intW.i)                             // Prints '1'
apply()(i: &intW.i)()
print(intW.i)                             // Prints '2'
```

I'm curious to why this is. I always thought that curried syntax was sugar for the higher ordered form of the function, but apparently there are semantic differences.

Additionally [this accepted proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md) to remove curried syntax from swift seems to state this is merely sugar, and I'm concerned we're losing more than syntax by removing this from the language. Is there a way to get the same functionality from a higher order function?

[image: Higher Order Function]
[image: Currying]

Comment: I am getting an error "Extra argument w in call" at : apply()(i: &intW.i, w: IntWrapper())().  Why do you have this extra parameter in case of curried syntax?. If I remove it, the results of manual and curried syntax versions are same.

Comment: Edited - I forgot to delete that while cleaning up my original source for this simpler example. I just tried this again in playgrounds and I can assure you the results are as stated. I'll see if I can add a screenshot.

Comment: I added some photos.